# how to copy values to field in aura:iteration dynamically using Radio button with multiple rows

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-iteration, radio-button

Here I'm trying to copy values from the output text table data to respect of their field which are price and Qty

Please take look at the below picture for an idea.

[image]

Here I'm using Inside two aura: iterations and I'm those price and qty from the different objects instead of entering the user he will just click and copy the values.

Please take a look at the below coding What I have return:

```
<div class="slds-section__content" id=" OrderLineItemsId">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.OrderItems}" var="item">
                    <table><tr>
                        <td><lightning:input label="S.No" value="" />  </td>
                        <td>
                        <lightning:input label="P/N" value="{!item.Name}" /> 
                        </td>
                        <td> <lightning:input label="P/N" value="{!item.client_Pn__c}" /> </td>

                        <td> <lightning:input label="Description" value="{!item.Description__c}" /> </td>
                        <td> <lightning:input label="Prod" value="{!item.Family__c}" /> </td>
                        <td> <lightning:input type="Date" label="Shipping Date" value="{!item.Confirmed_Shipping_Date__c}" /> </td>
                      <td> 
                            <aura:iteration items="{!item.Batch}" var="ba">
                                <table border="1" id="thispa">
                                    <tr><th> Price </th>
                                        <th> Qty </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                         <td> <ui:outputText title="Price" aura:id="baprice" value="{!ba.Unit_Price__c}"/>  </td>
                                         <td>  <ui:outputText title="Qty" aura:id="baqty" value="{!ba.Asked_Qty__c}" />  </td>
                                         <td> <ui:inputRadio aura:id="r0" name="select" label="Action" change="{!c.CopyValues}"/> </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </table>    
                             </aura:iteration>
                        </td>
                        <td> <lightning:input label="Qty" value="{!item.Quantity__c}" /> </td>
                        <td> <lightning:input label="Unit Pice" value="{!item.Price__c}" /> </td>

                        </tr>

                    </table>
                 </aura:iteration>    
            </div>
```

Controller:
What I need to do here is I need to get values for selected radio button and push them into respected row field(unit price and qty please look at that above image)

```
 CopyValues: function(component, event, helper) { 
       console.log("entered");

       var pricem=event.getSource();
       var selectedItemNew=document.getElementById(pricem).value();
       console.log(pricem.get("v.value"));   
       var table = document.getElementsById("thispa");  
         console.log(table);       
      }
```

Here I'm not able to get anything

Comment: what if in your 2nd iteration list `{!item.Batch}` has more than one row ? mean one `orderitem` had more than one `batch` ?

Comment: Yes we will have many batches for each and every row That's my problem I don't know, how can I get that?

Comment: we can get it but what values should display in `QTY & Unit Price`? ex: orderitemA had 2 batches with  like 1. price-2,qty-2 and 2.price-3,qty-3 then what values should be display in first table `Price & QTY` columns?

Comment: See Actually whatever I select(click on radio button) Whichever batch I select in that row that should copy to the unit Price and Qty from batches to that row input fields.
EXAMPLE:
1.Price-2 and Qty-2
2.Price-3 and Qty-3
if I select the radio button of second one the values should copy to that row inputFields of Unite price and Qty

Comment: Did you had a look into how Event Handling happens and how to work with Attributes in Aura?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_base_events.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_attr_values.htm?search_text=Action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i achieved by using `onclick` event  on child `tr` instead `radio button`. i used [HTML data-attribute](http://i%20just%20used%20%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes,) to bind parent row index and child row index, so i got both indexes when ever click on any child row then  `CopyValues` function calls and bind the selected child row values to parent row.
[image: result Image]

**cmp**

```
 <aura:attribute name="OrderItems" type="List" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<div class="slds-section">

            <aura:iteration items="{!v.OrderItems}" var="item" indexVar="index">
                  <table>
                      <tr>
                          <td> <lightning:input label="Family" value="{!item.family}" /> </td>
                          <td data-record="{!index}">
                               <aura:iteration items="{!item.batch}" var="ba" indexVar="childindex">
                                   <table border="1" id="thispa">
                                <tr><th> Price </th>
                                    <th> Qty </th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr data-record="{! childindex + '=>' + index}" class="{!'' +'=>'+index}" onclick="{!c.CopyValues}" >
                                     <td> <ui:outputText title="Price" aura:id="baprice" value="{!ba.price}"/>  </td>
                                     <td>  <ui:outputText title="Qty" aura:id="baqty" value="{!ba.askedqty}" />  </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                               </aura:iteration>
                          </td>
                          <td> <lightning:input label="QTY" value="{!item.qty}" /> </td>
                          <td> <lightning:input label="Unit Price" value="{!item.unitprice}" /> </td>
                      </tr>
                </table>
             </aura:iteration>    
        </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
doInit: function(component, event, helper){
    var data = [
        {
            "family": "P1",
            "batch": [
                {
                    "price": 10,
                    "askedqty": 2
                },
                {
                    "price": 20,
                    "askedqty": 4
                },
                {
                    "price": 30,
                    "askedqty": 6
                }
            ],
            "qty": '',
            "unitprice":'' 
        },
         {
            "family": "P2",
            "batch": [
                {
                    "price": 40,
                    "askedqty": 8
                },
                {
                    "price": 50,
                    "askedqty": 9
                },
                {
                    "price": 60,
                    "askedqty": 10
                }
            ],
            "qty": '',
            "unitprice":'' 
        }

    ];

    component.set("v.OrderItems",data);

},
CopyValues: function(component,event,helper){
     var childandparentindx = event.currentTarget.dataset.record.split('=>'),
         orderitems = component.get("v.OrderItems"),
         childindx = childandparentindx[0],
         parentindx = childandparentindx[1],
         selectedparentrow = orderitems[parentindx],
         selectedchildrow = selectedparentrow.batch[childindx];
         selectedparentrow.qty = selectedchildrow.askedqty;
         selectedparentrow.unitprice = selectedchildrow.price;
    orderitems.splice(parentindx, 1, selectedparentrow);
    console.log(orderitems);
    component.set("v.OrderItems",orderitems);

},

})
```

please upvote/accept if solution works for you. and let me know if you had any issues.

Comment: May I know about the concept that you used here to get that, how can I learn about those I mean I don't know what is this `event.currentTarget.dataset.record.split('=>'),`...etc
I want to learn about those